# How to translate Javascript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frameworks, coding-style

How to translate this code to jQuery? I am a newbie in the javascript world.

```
var show = document.querySelectorAll('.js-show');

for (let i = 0; i <= show.length; i++) {
    var hide = document.querySelectorAll('.js-hide');

    for (let i = 0; i <= hide.length; i++) {
        show[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (hide[i].type === 'password') {
                hide[i].type = 'text';
                show[i].innerHTML = 'visibility';
            } else {
                hide[i].type = 'password';
                show[i].innerHTML = 'visibility_off';
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thank's for your help.

Comment: jQuery to JS and vice-versa: http://codeblog.cz/vanilla/essentials.html#get-element-collection

Comment: Start by not doing this in every iteration `var hide = document.querySelectorAll('.js-hide');`

Comment: Also you can delegate in plain JS

Comment: Any specific reason you want to convert the Javascript to jQuery ?

Comment: Did you know that you can use other letters than `i` as a variable in the for loop? The variable can be multiple characters, even including numbers, as long as the number isn't the first character.

Comment: I want to know how to write in jQuery.

Comment: These days most people do the opposite, move away just jQuery to plain JS.

Comment: What is the intent of this code? You have 2 nested loops which both use the varible `i`. The code never uses the  `i` of the outer loop. I guess you want every `.show` elements to do something with alle `hide` elements, am I right?!

Comment: yes, I want to do something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vanilla JS is suboptimal. Also seeing your HTML would help

I believe you want this

```js
$('.js-show').on("click",function() {
  const $pw = $(this).closest(".someContainer").find(".pw");
  $pw.attr("type", $pw.attr("type")==="password" ? "text" : "password");
  $(this).val($pw.attr("type")==="password" ? "visibility" : "visibility_off");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someContainer">
  <input type="button" class="js-show" value="visibility" /> <input class="pw" type="password" />
</div>  
<div class="someContainer">
  <input type="button" class="js-show" value="visibility"/> <input class="pw" type="password" />
</div>
```